# Easy modification on jQuery code that checks if textboxes are empty. Need to check for textarea also

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script enables the submit button if a form if is filled up.
However I have a textarea

```
<textarea id="description" tabindex="15" style="width:500px;" name="description" cols="80" rows="10">
```

and I can not know how to add it for checking. If I type in all textboxes and leave the textarea empty, it will be submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').delegate('input:text, input:checkbox', 'blur keyup click change', function () {
        if(($('form input:text').filter(function(){ return $.trim(this.value) == ''; }).length > 0))
        {
          $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
        }
      else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$('form').delegate('input:text, input:checkbox', // rest of line
```

to

```
$('form').delegate('input:text, input:checkbox, textarea',
```

**EDIT**

The code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').delegate('input:text, input:checkbox, textarea', 'blur keyup click change', function () {
        if(($('form input:text, form textarea').filter(function(){ return $.trim(this.value) == ''; }).length > 0)) {
            $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that only detects that the text area has key input, but doesn't actually check it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').delegate('input:text, input:checkbox', 'textarea', 'blur keyup click change', function () {
        if(($('form input:text').filter(function(){ return $.trim(this.value) == ''; }).length > 0&&$('textarea').val()!==""&&$('textarea').val()!==null))
        {
          $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
        }
      else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: It does not submit it, even I wrote in all the fields

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'input:text, input:checkbox, textarea'` instead of `'input:text, input:checkbox', 'textarea'`?